# Table of Contents - page numbers separated using fixed number of spaces

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Is there a way to create a following table of contents?

```
Aaa  1
    Bbbbb  15
    Cc  25
```

Page numbers should be separated from text using spaces, not tabs.

With tabs, it looks ugly:

```
Aaa1
    Bbbbb  15
    Cc    25
```

In other words, I need exactly 2 spaces between each entry and the corresponding page number.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you mean in Markdown. could you post screenshots. Tabs are usually preferred because they will all line up properly, spaces need a lot of juggling.

Comment: @Tetsujin I need 2 spaces between each entry and the corresponding page number. I don't care about aligning. Just 2 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Table of Contents ("ToC") structure in the "Entries" tab of the ToC definition. How to open the ToC properties depends if you've already inserted a ToC in your document:

- if yes, right-click into the ToC and select "Edit Index";
- if not, got to Menu "Insert" -> "Table of Contents and Index" -> "Table of Contents, Index or Bibliografy".

The "Entries" tab contains the structure definition for every ToC Level. <del>To adapt all levels, you'll have to apply the required changes to every level separately.</del>

You'll need to modify the "Structure" definition. It's a combination of the following predefined elements and arbitrary text (or space) between them:

- <kbd>LS</kbd> **L**ink**S**tart - beginning of hyperlink to heading in text;
- <kbd>E#</kbd> **E**ntry Number - chapter number;
- <kbd>E</kbd> **E**ntry - chapter text (heading);
- <kbd>T</kbd> **T**abStop;
- <kbd>#</kbd> Page Number;
- <kbd>LE</kbd> **L**ink**E**nd - end of hyperlink to heading in text;

[image: ![enter image description here]

Select the <kbd>T</kbd> "button" (it's the tabstop between entry and page number, one should better name it "placeholder", but it looks like a simple button) and delete it. Now, put the cursor between the <kbd>E</kbd> "button" and the <kbd>#</kbd> "button" and hit <kbd>SPACE</kbd> twice. You can put arbitrary text content including spaces between the ToC elements. The ToC preview at the right should show how the resulting ToC line would look like.

<del>Repeat this for every ToC level (switch between levels using the List Box at the very left).</del>

After defining the ToC Entry Structure for Level 1, hit the <kbd>All</kbd> button at the right to apply the changes to all levels.

Comment: Exactly what I asked for. Thanks. LibreOffice UI in that part is quite counter-intuitive. It was quite unexpected that I can and need to **delete buttons**.